# Интерфейс шаблонов

Tags: c++, терминология

Что Скотт Майерс подразумевает под "Интерфейсами шаблонов" в своей книге "Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных советов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ"

> C++ изобилует интерфейсами. Интерфейсы функций. Интерфейсы классов.
>   Интерфейсы шаблонов. *Правило 18*

Comment: Тут можно перевести interface как  "взаимодействие". Или даже "через что взаимодействует"  пользователь с функциями , классами и шаблонами

Comment: А дальнейшее объяснение, как раз прямо по главе, в книге.

Comment: Имел в виду, если переводить из английского издания книги - "C++ is awash in interfaces"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего имеется в виду набор членов шаблона. Ведь что такое интерфейс? Просто как объект взаимодействует с окружающей средой:)

Только и всего...

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под членами шаблона

Answer (score 0):

Возможно под термином "Интерфейс шаблона" подразумеваются параметры шаблона.